# URL Rewriting with Query Strings using IIS URL Rewrite Module

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, query-string

I am trying to rewrite a url such as:

```
new_membership?R=1&I=2
```

to:

```
agent_new_membership.aspx?R=1&I=2
```

but I am getting an error reading: "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found"

This is the web.config code I am using:

```
    <rewrite>
  <rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="Redirects">
      <add key="/administration" value="/administration_main.aspx" />
      <add key="/change_admin_password" value="/admin_change_password.aspx" />
    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>

  <rules>
    <rule name="New Membership" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^new_membership?R=(\d+)&amp;I=(\d+)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="agent_new_membership.aspx?R={R:1}&amp;I={R:2}" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Redirect rule1 for Redirects">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>        
  </rules>

</rewrite>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
    <rule name="TestRule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^new_membership\?R=(\d+)&amp;I=(\d+)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="agent_new_membership.aspx?R={R:1}&amp;I={R:2}" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. I have updated the original post to include the full rewrite code based on your suggestion, in case it is conflicting with something else.

Comment: Updated the pattern but still no luck :(